# Plotly zoomed marker area

Tags: python, plotly, zooming

I have multiple markers (expressed as latitude,longitude) on my map (I am using Scatter Geo), all of them with edge thourgh them.

I need to get a zoomed view for some marker and save that view to a .png file.

I could do this manually, zooming every intersted marker and taking the screenshot but I would like to do it via code.

How is it possible to create a loop for a markers list and take screenshot of the area around a specific marker?

A circle/area with marker in the center and a radius of 5km could be enough

Comment: in this case i think i would loop through each marker, create a fig, and then output with [orca](https://plotly.com/python/orca-management/), but it's hard to get specific without seeing what you have so far.

Comment: @jayveesea the problem here is that I have for example edge like (A,C), (B,C) that are far away from C geographically, and I want to zoom on C and showing edges going to A and B, I don't care if A and B node are visible

Comment: The problem is not how to create a figure with all edges and nodes, but how to zoom a specific node after the entire figure has been done

Comment: to clarify, plot only the point you want to see, take a snapshot, and move to the next point and repeat.

Comment: @jayveesea I can't plot only one point, I need edges and also the USA map, I could manually zoom every node but this will bring to very bad result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Scattergeo` you can use `center` and `projection_scale` to home into an area.

[`projection_scale`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-geo-projection-scale) is similar to zoom level and not an obvious argument to use:

> Zooms in or out on the map view. A scale of "1" corresponds to the
>   largest zoom level that fits the map's lon and lat ranges.

Below is an example adapted from [here](https://plotly.com/python/scatter-plots-on-maps/#styled-us-airports-map).

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('2011_february_us_airport_traffic.csv')
df['text'] = df['airport'] + '' + df['city'] + ', ' + df['state'] + '' + 'Arrivals: ' + df['cnt'].astype(str)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(
        lon = df['long'], lat = df['lat'],
        text = df['text'],
        mode = 'markers',
        marker_color = df['cnt'],
        ))

fig.update_layout(
        title = 'Most trafficked US airports<br>(Hover for airport names)',
        geo = dict(
            scope='usa',
            projection_type='albers usa',
            showland = True
        ))

# focus point
lat_foc = 35.21401111
lon_foc = -80.94312583
fig.update_layout(
        geo = dict(
            projection_scale=10, #this is kind of like zoom
            center=dict(lat=lat_foc, lon=lon_foc), # this will center on the point
        ))

fig.show()
```